# PayPal money funnelling?

Tags: paypal

**Problem:** I have my own bank account and make my own money but my parents still keep tabs on what I'm doing with it. They always look through my bank statements and question things. Coming from a family where paying more than £20 for a jumper is frowned upon, I try and avoid directly paying for expensive things online as they will see and I will feel guilty.

**Solution:** I've had an idea to try and use PayPal to make smaller frequent payments and then pay for something big with PayPal.

**Question:** Will this one big payment be shown on my bank statement?

Comment: Are you a minor? Or an adult?

Comment: @ceejayoz 17, a minor where I live.

Comment: In that case, you are likely to have trouble *getting* a PayPal account. In a year (at most), you'll have complete freedom and should create new accounts your parents don't have access to at that point. For now, you're under their care... I can't speak for the UK but in the US parents have full rights over their minor childrens' finances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worrying about the statement is only part of the problem, and probably not the right question.

To sever a surveillance link:

Open a new bank account if you are old enough, turn on electronic statements such that the statement is never delivered physically for inspection.

Disclaimer: This is not advice for a parent child relationship. This is the answer on how to sever a surveillance link in any civil circumstance.

Comment: You can also rent a PO box, and get your mail there. Costs a bit, but is good for all mail.

Answer (score 1):

> Will this one big payment be shown on my bank statement?

Yes.  All transfers to and from PayPal (including immediate purchases) will show up on your bank statement.

Comment: However (in my country) you can transfer money from your bank account to paypal (in smaller increments) and then use the paypal balance to pay for things.